# Best kind of web editors for SharePoint

Tags: html-editor

Right now my team and I are using the RadEditor by Telerik in our SharePoint 2010 enterprise.  We are not blown away by it as it seems very basic/limited.  I'm curious to know what the SharePoint community thinks are the top editors to go with for SharePoint 2010 or 2013.  We don't have too many HTML folks editing data (like myself).  Instead we have more social media professionals adding news content with images with our editor.  So if anyone has any good ideas to make their lives easier, that would be fantastic!

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you have not enabled its Accessible UI? This is a site feature that can improve the experience for people with disabilities, but it greatly limits the feature set because rich text editing is, ultimately, a visual operation. You can see how it looks like here - http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/accessibleeditor/defaultcs.aspx so if you see the same editor - you are using the limited version. Here is how to see which features you have enabled http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/moss-sp2010-using-radeditor-in-list-items.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used TinyMCE in a situation or 2.

I followed Josh McCarty's walkthrough and it worked pretty well.

http://joshmccarty.com/2011/06/use-tinymce-as-the-rich-text-editor-in-sharepoint-forms/